# Save file in vim before search with FZF

Tags: vim, fzf

I have this mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader><space> :Files<CR>
```

This works fine, but when I have a changed file already open, I get an error when I switch to a new file.

Is it possible to save the file before starting fzf?
I tried something like this, but this doesn't work if I don't have a file open. (start vi without file and start fzf)

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader><space> :w<CR>:Files<CR>
```

Comment: `:help 'hidden'`

Comment: Just as a suggestion (and of course it's a matter of taste) but you should see how you like mapping just space (without leader) for FZF, then it's just one key!  Unless of course you have space mapped to something else.

Comment: I have space as leader. So I just do a double space to start FZF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, use `:update` instead of `:write`. This will only write if there are indeed unpersisted changes.

You can check for an empty buffer with `empty(bufname(''))`, but as there are other corner cases, I would rather just silence the error:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader><space> :execute 'silent! update'<Bar>Files<CR>
```

#### Alternative

Alternatively, you can look into the `'hidden'` option, as @romainl mentioned. With this, Vim won't complain if a buffer that has unsaved changes is not shown in a window any longer, and only confront you on quitting Vim. Many power users have `:set hidden`.

Comment: For my education, what if we simply set `autowrite` in `vimrc`

Comment: @dlmeetei: That would probably work, too (depending on how FZF changes the buffer). But it would affect many (built-in) commands, too, not be limited to FZF invocation.

Comment: Ok,Thanks Ingo, Your answer always help. I usually set `aw`, generally, is it good practice or bad?

Comment: @dlmeetei: If it works for you, fine. That's what all those options are for: To tweak the application for your personal preferences, expectations, and workflow.